# Module with LM7815 and LM7915 voltage regulators has 3 pins for input and output - why?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

Why does [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NY9MFNT) +-15 V voltage regulator have 3 pins at the input and at the output?

Comment: The question title and text are about different issues. Title asks about the voltage regulators, the question body about the whole PCB. 
As it's apparently a symmetric power supply (+ and - outputs), how would it work with less than three pins? Also, each regulator needs a reference to measure it's output voltage. That will not work with two pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has two voltage regulators on board, and can handle two input voltages, positive and negative plus common ground, and has two outputs, one for the +15 V, one for the -15 V, plus common ground. The voltage regulators both need this ground to work, and you need it at the output.

Answer (score 1):

It needs positive, negative and common ground input to regulate positive and negative output in relation to the common ground output.